# Why does the compiler give the error "The name 'identifier' does not exist in the current context"?

Tags: c#, generics

Here's the context (C#).

```
public class Base
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {

    }
}

public class Intermediate<TIntermediateTypeParam>
{

}

public class Derived<TDerivedTypeParam> : Intermediate<string>
{
    public void SomethingElse()
    {
        SomeMethod(); // Error: The name 'SomeMethod' does not exist in the current context.
    }
}
```

This was unexpected.
Any explanations as to why and how to fix it?

Comment: Changing to this: `public class Intermediate<TIntermediateTypeParam> : Base` "fixes" it for me.

Comment: Hint: please avoid multi-tagging. In other words: read the descriptions of tags before using them. You have a very basic C# language question; you dont need class or design tags for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Intermediate` doesn't subclass `Base` which is where the method is, therefore it is not part of the `Derived` class and `Derived` can't access it directly.

You would either need to call it from an instance of `Base` or have `Intermediate` (or `Derived`) subclass `Base`

Comment: Doh! Thanks. I'm having this problem in a more complex context and tried simplifying it, got the same error (because of stupidity) and posted the question. This is the solution to the simplified context but it's not the problem in the more complex scenario. Off to try to isolate the problem in the real world code...